# Relate any value to the identifier of an entity using only the structure of entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, sonata-admin

I want to get the following SQL structure

```sql
    SELECT * FROM payment as P INNER JOIN paymentType as PT ON P.paymentTypeId = PT.paymentTypeId AND PT.language = ?
```

On “?” I want to change the question symbol for 1, for example.

How do I get that whenever they are related they take a value from the entity for the language value?

```php
    class Payment {
      private int $id;
      private int $paymentTypeId;
    }

    class PaymentType {
      private int $id;
      private int $language;
    }
```

Relations

```xml
    <entity name="Payment" >
      <id name="id" type="integer"/>
      <field name="paymentTypeId" type="integer" />
      <many-to-one field="paymentType" target-entity="PaymentType">
        <join-columns>
            <join-column name="payment_type_id" referenced-column-name="id"/>
        </join-columns>
      </many-to-one>
    </entity>
    
    <entity name="PaymentType" >
      <id name="id" type="integer"/>
      <id name="language" type="integer" />
    </entity>
```